# How can I upload photos rejected as corrupted to Blurb Books?

Tags: file-transfer, error

I am trying to create a wedding album on the Blurb Books and so far have managed to upload most photos. 
I got a message for some of the uploaded pictures stating the file was corrupted or empty or didn't exist, therefore, rejecting it. 
How can I upload these photos?
Please would love some suggestions as I would like to have these pics in my album.

Comment: Are the file sizes of the rejected images much larger than the ones that succeeded?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you already checked the integrity of those files (ie. file exist, you can open it and see the picuture).

I have three suggestions:

1- Use Picasa to upload the pictures that were not accepted by Blurb.
There is a place in the Blurb website that explains how to do that.

OR

2- Pass those problematic files in the Picasa file exporter and save them in a specific folder. After that, luckily Picasa will "fix" any file corrupted for any reason. Than you can try to upload them again.

OR

3- Either using Picasa or any other application, export those files from the original format (JPG? PNG? TIFF?) to another format and try to upload those new files.